# Error in terms.formula : '.' in formula and no 'data' argument for linear regression

Tags: r, regression, linear-regression, lm

I was writing a simple code for multiple linear regression in R. The code is as follows.

```
dataset$State = factor (dataset$State, 
                        levels = c ('New York','California','Florida'), 
                        labels = c ('1','2','3') ) 
#Splitting the dataset 
library(caTools) 
set.seed(123) 
split = sample.split(dataset$Profit, SplitRatio = 0.8) 
training_set = subset(dataset$Profit, split == TRUE)
test_set = subset(dataset$Profit, split == FALSE) 

#Fitting Multiple Linear Regression to the Training set 
regressor = lm(formula = Profit ~ ., data = training_set)
```

But i get this error when running.

> Error in terms.formula(formula, data = data) :    '.' in formula and
>   no 'data' argument

Why gives such an error?

---

`dataset` at https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1M5HAKs1s2ABYMEzVYMwWUaATlCw2ayZC?usp=sharing

Comment: Does `lm(formula = mpg ~ ., data = mtcars)` throw a similar error?

Comment: lm(formula = mpg ~ ., data = mtcars) did not return errors.

Comment: #Encoding categorical Data
dataset$State = factor (dataset$State,
                            levels = c ('New York','California','Florida'),
                            labels = c ('1','2','3')
                            )

#Splitting the dataset 
library(caTools)
set.seed(123)
split = sample.split(dataset$Profit, SplitRatio = 0.8)
training_set = subset(dataset$Profit, split == TRUE)
test_set = subset(dataset$Profit, split == FALSE)
#Fitting Multiple Linear Regression to the Training set
regressor = lm(formula = Profit ~ .,
               data = training_set)

Comment: @Nide ; you can add the info to your question if  you click [`edit`](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/51230485/edit) under your question . Also can you post the results of `str(training_set)` please.

Comment: okay to reproduce the error : `x = 1:10 ; lm(x ~  .)` so I'd guess  your code to create  `training_data` is not correct

Comment: > str(training_set)
 num [1:40] 192262 191792 191050 156991 156123 ...

Comment: okay, thanks Nide. So you can see that `training_set` is just one variable / vector, and not a data.frame with multiple variables - looks like you are splitting the dataset, and using subset incorrectly.

Comment: "it already splited the dataset"> test_set
 [1] 182901.99 166187.94 155752.60 146121.95 129917.04 122776.86 118474.03 108733.99
 [9]  99937.59  97483.56
> training_set
 [1] 192261.83 191792.06 191050.39 156991.12 156122.51 152211.77 149759.96 144259.40
 [9] 141585.52 134307.35 132602.65 126992.93 125370.37 124266.90 111313.02 110352.25
[17] 108552.04 107404.34 105733.54 105008.31 103282.38 101004.64  97427.84  96778.92
[25]  96712.80  96479.51  90708.19  89949.14  81229.06  81005.76  78239.91  77798.83
[33]  71498.49  69758.98  65200.33  64926.08  49490.75  42559.73  35673.41  14681.40

Comment: This is the data   https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1M5HAKs1s2ABYMEzVYMwWUaATlCw2ayZC?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for making this reproducible

```
dataset <- 
structure(list(R.D.Spend = c(165349.2, 162597.7, 153441.51, 144372.41, 
142107.34, 131876.9, 134615.46, 130298.13, 120542.52, 123334.88, 
101913.08, 100671.96, 93863.75, 91992.39, 119943.24, 114523.61, 
78013.11, 94657.16, 91749.16, 86419.7, 76253.86, 78389.47, 73994.56, 
67532.53, 77044.01, 64664.71, 75328.87, 72107.6, 66051.52, 65605.48, 
61994.48, 61136.38, 63408.86, 55493.95, 46426.07, 46014.02, 28663.76, 
44069.95, 20229.59, 38558.51, 28754.33, 27892.92, 23640.93, 15505.73, 
22177.74, 1000.23, 1315.46, 0, 542.05, 0), Administration = c(136897.8, 
151377.59, 101145.55, 118671.85, 91391.77, 99814.71, 147198.87, 
145530.06, 148718.95, 108679.17, 110594.11, 91790.61, 127320.38, 
135495.07, 156547.42, 122616.84, 121597.55, 145077.58, 114175.79, 
153514.11, 113867.3, 153773.43, 122782.75, 105751.03, 99281.34, 
139553.16, 144135.98, 127864.55, 182645.56, 153032.06, 115641.28, 
152701.92, 129219.61, 103057.49, 157693.92, 85047.44, 127056.21, 
51283.14, 65947.93, 82982.09, 118546.05, 84710.77, 96189.63, 
127382.3, 154806.14, 124153.04, 115816.21, 135426.92, 51743.15, 
116983.8), Marketing.Spend = c(471784.1, 443898.53, 407934.54, 
383199.62, 366168.42, 362861.36, 127716.82, 323876.68, 311613.29, 
304981.62, 229160.95, 249744.55, 249839.44, 252664.93, 256512.92, 
261776.23, 264346.06, 282574.31, 294919.57, 0, 298664.47, 299737.29, 
303319.26, 304768.73, 140574.81, 137962.62, 134050.07, 353183.81, 
118148.2, 107138.38, 91131.24, 88218.23, 46085.25, 214634.81, 
210797.67, 205517.64, 201126.82, 197029.42, 185265.1, 174999.3, 
172795.67, 164470.71, 148001.11, 35534.17, 28334.72, 1903.93, 
297114.46, 0, 0, 45173.06), State = structure(c(1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 
3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 
2L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 
3L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 2L), .Label = c("1", 
"2", "3"), class = "factor"), Profit = c(192261.83, 191792.06, 
191050.39, 182901.99, 166187.94, 156991.12, 156122.51, 155752.6, 
152211.77, 149759.96, 146121.95, 144259.4, 141585.52, 134307.35, 
132602.65, 129917.04, 126992.93, 125370.37, 124266.9, 122776.86, 
118474.03, 111313.02, 110352.25, 108733.99, 108552.04, 107404.34, 
105733.54, 105008.31, 103282.38, 101004.64, 99937.59, 97483.56, 
97427.84, 96778.92, 96712.8, 96479.51, 90708.19, 89949.14, 81229.06, 
81005.76, 78239.91, 77798.83, 71498.49, 69758.98, 65200.33, 64926.08, 
49490.75, 42559.73, 35673.41, 14681.4)), .Names = c("R.D.Spend", 
"Administration", "Marketing.Spend", "State", "Profit"), row.names = c(NA, 
-50L), class = "data.frame")
```

The issue is with subsetting. Replace

```
training_set = subset(dataset$Profit, split == TRUE)
test_set = subset(dataset$Profit, split == FALSE)
```

with

```
training_set = subset(dataset, subset = split)
test_set = subset(dataset, subset = !split)

lm(formula = Profit ~ ., data = training_set)

#Call:
#lm(formula = Profit ~ ., data = training_set)
#
#Coefficients:
#    (Intercept)        R.D.Spend   Administration  Marketing.Spend  
#      4.965e+04        7.986e-01       -2.942e-02        3.268e-02  
#         State2           State3  
#      1.213e+02        2.376e+02
```