# Trying to remove variables with a factor of 1, but i keep getting "Error in terms.formula(formula, data = data) : in formula and no 'data' argument

Tags: r, logistic-regression

My dataset is large and to try and fit a logistic model, i need to find and remove all the variables that have a factor of 1. My dataset is dataframeX9R Here is my current code:

```
values_count <- sapply(lapply(dataframeX9R, unique), length)  # Identify variables with value
values_count

attach(dataframeX9R)
logisticmodel<- glm(DEFBENRP~., dataframeX9R[, values_count > 1], family = "binomial")
```

Iv identified the variables i want (i think), but when i try to subset them out and fit the model i getting this error:

> Error in terms.formula(formula, data = data) : '.' in formula and no
> 'data' argument

Im not sure what to do here, i dont want to list every variable in the dataset because it is simply too large, and going into the excel file to remove these variables manually is not viable either. Sorry if this is not reproducible.

Comment: What data type is `dataframeX9R`? You should probably recheck the syntax of `dataframeX9R[, values_count > 1]` to make sure it returns what you are expecting.

Comment: Its a dataframe with a bunch of integer and character variables. There are tons of variables with only characters. Is the issue the character data?

Comment: This sample data does not replicate the error, so I am not sure what is wrong with your `data.frame`: `dataframeX9R <- data.frame(DEFBENRP = sample(0:1, 5, TRUE), a = 1:5, b = rep(1, 5), c = 1:5)`. The error has been encountered before, see for example https://stackoverflow.com/q/51230485/3560695